# How to send raw data in flutter http

Tags: flutter, http, postman

I wanted to send raw data in flutter http and the data doesn't look like `JSON`

Here's how I done that in Postman[image]

and tried this in flutter using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http),

```
 Response res = await post(
      Uri.parse(baseUrl + endPoint),
      headers: {'Client-ID': clientId, 'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
      body: jsonEncode('fields *'),
    );
```

and got this in console,

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

Comment: You can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878530/15721679 it works for me

Comment: This error is not about the wrong code because in this error, XMLHttpRequest  (CORS), so I told completely on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625229/how-to-fix-xmlhttprequest-cors-exceptions-on-flutter-web-projects

Answer (score 3):

Add it as this

```
var headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  
};
var request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('Your url'));
request.body = '''fields *''';
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

Or you can easily see it being implemented in `Postman`'s code request to the right just select the code icon and choose http-Dart