# How to fix XMLHttpRequest (CORS) exceptions on Flutter web projects

Tags: json, flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

My problem

Finally, I found the errors in my project and not related to null variables and were related to XMLHttpRequest (CORS) on Flutter web projects that I thought related to null variables. however, I decided to change my title topic and say what problem exists

My Json :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "status_code": 200,
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "message": "sussecc!",
        "has_paginate": 0,
        "results": {
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "full_name": "emin",
                "phone_number": "+1125585",
                "admin_role": "0",
                "national_id": "21",
                "address": null,
                "is_active": "1",
                "email": null,
                "email_verified_at": "2023-12-04 20:41:41",
                "created_at": "2023-12-04T17:11:42.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-12-04T17:11:42.000000Z"
            },
            "token": "31|ssasdsdfsdgeedewfsdvfdbdfve3svxfb"
        }
    }
}
```

My Model Class :

```
class ModelLoginService {
  ModelLoginService({
    required this.success,
    required this.statusCode,
    required this.error,
    required this.data,
  });
  late final bool success;
  late final int statusCode;
  late final dynamic? error;
  late final Data? data;

  ModelLoginService.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    success = json['success'];
    statusCode = json['status_code'];
    error = Error.fromJson(json['error']);
    data = Data.fromJson(json['data']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['success'] = success;
    _data['status_code'] = statusCode;
    _data['error'] = error!.toJson() == null ? null : error.toJson();
    _data['data'] = data!.toJson() == null ? null : error.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Error {
  Error({
    required this.message,
    required this.errors,
  });
  late final String? message;
  late final Errors? errors;

  Error.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json['message'];
    errors = Errors.fromJson(json['errors']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['message'] = message!;
    _data['errors'] = errors!.toJson().isEmpty;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Errors {
  Errors({
    required this.reason,
    required this.message,
  });
  late final String reason;
  late final String message;

  Errors.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    reason = json['reason'];
    message = json['message'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['reason'] = reason;
    _data['message'] = message;
    return _data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.message,
    required this.hasPaginate,
    required this.results,
  });
  late final String message;
  late final int hasPaginate;
  late final Results results;

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json['message'];
    hasPaginate = json['has_paginate'];
    results = Results.fromJson(json['results']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['message'] = message;
    _data['has_paginate'] = hasPaginate;
    _data['results'] = results.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Results {
  Results({
    required this.user,
    required this.token,
  });
  late final User user;
  late final String token;

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    user = User.fromJson(json['user']);
    token = json['token'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['user'] = user.toJson();
    _data['token'] = token;
    return _data;
  }
}

class User {
  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.adminRole,
    required this.nationalId,
    required this.address,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.email,
    required this.emailVerifiedAt,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });
  late final int id;
  late final String fullName;
  late final String phoneNumber;
  late final String adminRole;
  late final String nationalId;
  late final String? address;
  late final String isActive;
  late final String? email;
  late final String emailVerifiedAt;
  late final String createdAt;
  late final String updatedAt;

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    fullName = json['full_name'];
    phoneNumber = json['phone_number'];
    adminRole = json['admin_role'];
    nationalId = json['national_id'];
    address = json['address'] == null ? null : json['address'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];
    email = json['email'] == null ? null : json['email'];
    emailVerifiedAt = json['email_verified_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['id'] = id;
    _data['full_name'] = fullName;
    _data['phone_number'] = phoneNumber;
    _data['admin_role'] = adminRole;
    _data['national_id'] = nationalId;
    _data['address'] = address;
    _data['is_active'] = isActive;
    _data['email'] = email;
    _data['email_verified_at'] = emailVerifiedAt;
    _data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    _data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

My service for get JSON

```
class ServiceLogin extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  Map<String, String> authorizationh = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> bodyMap = {};
  String username = "", password = "";

  Future<ModelLoginService> postData() async {
    bodyMap = {
      'full_name': 'admin',
      'password': 'c1992885',
    };

    var response = await post('http://test.com/admin/api/login', bodyMap);

    print('response.body ${response.body}');
    return ModelLoginService.fromJson(response.body);
  }
}
```

Error Log

```
Performing hot restart...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Edge...
Restarted application in 743ms.
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "ApiController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ApiController" has been initialized
response.body null
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 127:3       castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 818:12  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart 652:14     as_C
packages/shndz_panel/services/service_login.dart 21:30                            postData
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 655:5                                         [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 745:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7                <fn>
```

I used nullable type in flutter in my model and expected this problem not to occur and i can't find the best way to solve it

Comment: Your response.body seems to be null. Looks like your API call is not returning anything.

Comment: @Andrija
 what do you think? I copied this code from my previous project, which worked fine, but Jason was different

Comment: your post call to http:// test.com does not return anything.

Comment: Make sure to use the right url. I'm pretty sure `http://test.com/admin/api/login` is not right

Comment: I changed my address, it is valid

Comment: Can you check the Network tab in devTools to make sure your API is correct?

Comment: yes but for this topic of privacy, I change the domain from text and i know my domain it is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the main problem that was preventing API calls in Web Flutter. so I finally found on search and set an answer in my topic**

> **XMLHttpRequest (CORS) exception on every flutter web**
>
> I've spent time on it and did research. The issue is there and needs
> highlighting. A lot of people are facing this issue it can be verified
> upon doing a single search on Google and there's no solution to it
> directly within Flutter.
>
> The CORS problem can be resolved only if I am the developer of the
> API. I can add CORS configuration to it or the server and it'll work
> fine in Flutter Web but upon using 3rd party API it keeps on giving
> errors that can't be resolved. I've tried multiple publicly available
> APIs.
>
> The only way I found out is to make middleware API of the 3rd party
> API, add CORS configuration to it, and then use it in Flutter Web but
> instead of all this process shouldn't Flutter Web directly able to
> manage all of these hassles?

Answer (score 0):

Use this optional model instead of required model however it is always recommended to to use data part of json and get. check on success or status code
import 'dart:convert';

```
class UserLoginModel {
    final bool? success;
    final int? statusCode;
    final dynamic error;
    final Data? data;

    UserLoginModel({
        this.success,
        this.statusCode,
        this.error,
        this.data,
    });

    factory UserLoginModel.fromRawJson(String str) => UserLoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory UserLoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserLoginModel(
        success: json["success"],
        statusCode: json["status_code"],
        error: json["error"],
        data: json["data"] == null ? null : Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "status_code": statusCode,
        "error": error,
        "data": data?.toJson(),
    };
}

class Data {
    final String? message;
    final int? hasPaginate;
    final Results? results;

    Data({
        this.message,
        this.hasPaginate,
        this.results,
    });

    factory Data.fromRawJson(String str) => Data.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        message: json["message"],
        hasPaginate: json["has_paginate"],
        results: json["results"] == null ? null : Results.fromJson(json["results"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "message": message,
        "has_paginate": hasPaginate,
        "results": results?.toJson(),
    };
}

class Results {
    final User? user;
    final String? token;

    Results({
        this.user,
        this.token,
    });

    factory Results.fromRawJson(String str) => Results.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Results(
        user: json["user"] == null ? null : User.fromJson(json["user"]),
        token: json["token"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "user": user?.toJson(),
        "token": token,
    };
}

class User {
    final int? id;
    final String? fullName;
    final String? phoneNumber;
    final String? adminRole;
    final String? nationalId;
    final dynamic address;
    final String? isActive;
    final dynamic email;
    final DateTime? emailVerifiedAt;
    final DateTime? createdAt;
    final DateTime? updatedAt;

    User({
        this.id,
        this.fullName,
        this.phoneNumber,
        this.adminRole,
        this.nationalId,
        this.address,
        this.isActive,
        this.email,
        this.emailVerifiedAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
    });

    factory User.fromRawJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        fullName: json["full_name"],
        phoneNumber: json["phone_number"],
        adminRole: json["admin_role"],
        nationalId: json["national_id"],
        address: json["address"],
        isActive: json["is_active"],
        email: json["email"],
        emailVerifiedAt: json["email_verified_at"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["email_verified_at"]),
        createdAt: json["created_at"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "full_name": fullName,
        "phone_number": phoneNumber,
        "admin_role": adminRole,
        "national_id": nationalId,
        "address": address,
        "is_active": isActive,
        "email": email,
        "email_verified_at": emailVerifiedAt?.toIso8601String(),
        "created_at": createdAt?.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt?.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

Comment: This way is useful for checking null variables in models but is not related to my error because of an error about XMLHttpRequest (CORS) I said in my answer how can fix it. so checked the green tick if anyone has a problem calling API in Flutter web app

Comment: I see Thats Great 

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON response seems to have some nullable fields, such as `address` and `email`. When mapping these fields to your model, you need to account for the possibility that these fields might be `null` in the JSON.

In your `User.fromJson` method, you're already handling the conversion of nullable fields like `address` and `email` by checking if they are null in the JSON and assigning them accordingly:

```
address = json['address'] == null ? null : json['address'];
email = json['email'] == null ? null : json['email'];
```

However, the issue might arise if the `error` or `data` fields in your JSON response are `null`. Your `ModelLoginService.fromJson` method assumes these fields will always contain valid JSON objects, causing the error when encountering null.

To handle this, you should check for nullability at each level when parsing JSON. For example, in `ModelLoginService.fromJson`, you can modify the parsing of `error` and `data`:

```
error = json['error'] != null ? Error.fromJson(json['error']) : null;
data = json['data'] != null ? Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
```

This way, if `error` or `data` is `null` in the JSON, you assign null to the corresponding variable in your model class, avoiding potential errors.

Similarly, in your `Data.fromJson` method, you can adjust the parsing of results:

```
results = json['results'] != null ? Results.fromJson(json['results']) : Results();
```

This approach ensures that if any part of your JSON response is `null`, the corresponding object in your model will also be `null` or a default/empty object.

Remember to handle these nullable objects appropriately in your code wherever you're using this model to avoid null pointer exceptions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: unfortunately, I have developed the app in Web flutter and I found the Errors depend on XMLHttpRequest which happens when calling API.
I tried  just found one way that must run flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security" but this is not the solution and it doesn't work in the release. Adding CORS to headers also doesn't work.

Comment: please, check the green tick if anyone has a problem calling API in the Flutter web app.